# How to change between two icons upon every time a button is pressed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Take for example we have an IconButton:

IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.add)
onPressed: (){
//Every time this button is pressed the add icon changes to a tick icon, and when it is pressed again, the tick icon changes to an add icon
}
);

My attempt on the

```
Widget add = const Icon(Icons.add);
Widget tick = const Icon(Icons.tick);

Widget select(){
 : add
 ? tick
 return //I am not sure what I will be returning
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once try to this demo

**Define variable for change**

```
bool change = true;
```

**Put in your widget body**

```
Center(
    child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            change = !change;
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(change ? Icons.call : Icons.mail_outline, size: 35)),
  ),
```

if you have use to icon button then put onTap same as in IconButton's OnPress method.

Comment: Thank you @Romil it worked. Now, I've got to figure out how to differentiate between several buttons because now if I press one button it changes the icons of all the icons in all buttons instead of one button alone

Answer (score 1):

You can use StatefulWidget and `setState`

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = !selected;
                });
              },
              icon:
                  selected ? const Icon(Icons.add) : const Icon(Icons.check))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Soliev it worked. now I've got to figure out how to make it work for several buttons individually. because currently when I press one button it changes the icons on all buttons.

Comment: If you use one variable for several buttons in this case `selected` they all change at the same time. You need to have several variables or you can use lists

Comment: Brilliant! Several variables worked out as I wanted